# Please help merging 4 MySQL queries to One

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE RIA.Contact SET title = REPLACE(title, 'Cheif', 'Chief') where title rlike 'Cheif';
UPDATE RIA.Contact SET title = REPLACE(title, 'Manger', 'Manager') where title rlike 'Manger';
UPDATE RIA.Contact SET title = REPLACE(title, 'Manging', 'Managing') where title rlike 'Manging';
UPDATE RIA.Contact SET title = REPLACE(title, 'Excutive', 'Executive') where title rlike 'Excutive';
```

Can we merge the above 4 to something like this : `UPDATE table SET A = IF(A > 0 AND A < 1, 1, IF(A > 1 AND A < 2, 2, A)) WHERE A IS NOT NULL;`

I know we can do this using a procedure but is it possible just using a query?

I tried this -

`UPDATE RIA.Contact SET title = IF(title rlike 'Cheif', replace(title,'Cheif','Chief'), IF(title rlike 'Manger', replace(title,'Manger','Manager'))) WHERE title rlike 'Cheif' or title rlike 'Manger';`

no go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE RIA.Contact
SET title = REPLACE(
  REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE(title, 'Excutive', 'Executive'),
      'Manging', 'Managing'),
    'Manger', 'Manager'),
  'Cheif', 'Chief')
WHERE title rlike 'Cheif'
   OR title rlike 'Manger'
   OR title rlike 'Manging'
   OR title rlike 'Excutive';
```

Comment: This totally works! Can we use If Then Else for making the query lot simpler?

Comment: I don't think you can use If-Then-Else in this context.

Comment: Thanks Adrian! I just wish MySQL had some more features but I am happy with it!