# Merging multiple MySQL SELECT statements calculating fields

Tags: mysql, delphi

I've had a look at this question ([Please help merging 4 MySQL queries to One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944117/please-help-merging-4-mysql-queries-to-one)) hoping it would help, but it doesn't. I can't make sense of it because my brain is fried.

I'm trying to get my head around merging four SELECT statements, all of which work individually, into one.

The fields are;

*QUANTITY: INT;*

*ORDERDATE: DATE;* // Not datetime - I don't need time.

*MySQL Version 5.6.17*

The data I'm retrieving is;

**1) Number of products ordered this financial year;**

```
SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) AS YTD
  FROM ORDERDETAILS
  WHERE ORDERDATE BETWEEN "2016-07-01" AND "2017-02-16"
```

*Note that in Australia the Financial Year is 1st of July through to 30th of June.*

**2) Number of products ordered this month;**

```
SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) AS MONTHY
  FROM ORDERDETAILS
  WHERE ORDERDATE BETWEEN "2017-02-01" AND "2017-02-16"
```

**3) Number of products ordered today;**

```
SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) AS TODAYS
  FROM ORDERDETAILS
  WHERE ORDERDATE = "2017-02-16"
```

**4) Average number of products ordered per order;**

```
SELECT AVG(QUANTITY) AS BOOGER
  FROM ORDERDETAILS
  WHERE ORDERDATE BETWEEN "2016-07-01" AND "2017-02-16"
```

I want to avoid sending four separate statements to the server. Perhaps it can't be done, but if I could achieve the same results in a single statement I'd be happy.

I've looked at joins, embedding select within selects but can't get my head around it.

Once I get the data all I do is update a couple of labels on a form (Delphi).

Any tips that a nearly 55 year old brain can handle would be appreciated.

Comment: What would the desired result look like? And see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry all I want is the numbers. The existing SELECTs work and produce a single number which I display on screen. I guess merging them should return four numbers. I'll check out the answer posted and see if it works. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SUM(IF())` pattern and move condition inside the `IF`.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(IF(ORDERDATE BETWEEN "2016-07-01" AND "2017-02-16", QUANTITY, 0)) AS YTD,
  SUM(IF(ORDERDATE BETWEEN "2017-02-01" AND "2017-02-16", QUANTITY, 0)) AS MONTHY,
  SUM(IF(ORDERDATE = "2017-02-16", QUANTITY, 0)) AS TODAYS,
  SUM(IF(ORDERDATE BETWEEN "2016-07-01" AND "2017-02-16", QUANTITY, 0)) / COUNT(IF(ORDERDATE BETWEEN "2016-07-01" AND "2017-02-16", 1, NULL)) AS BOOGER
FROM ORDERDETAILS
WHERE ORDERDATE BETWEEN "2016-07-01" AND "2017-02-16";
```

Consider using `CURDATE()` for today's date.

Also a `WHERE` clause can be added so that all rows of table are not scanned e.g. `WHERE ORDERDATE BETWEEN "2016-07-01" AND "2017-02-16"` after `FROM ORDERDETAILS`

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. But I'm confused by your final comment about adding WHERE after ORDERDETAILS. I'm already doing that aren't I?

Comment: In my answer, I have moved conditions for `SUM` inside `SUM(IF())` and query works fine. But as there is no WHERE clause in query, it will scan all rows of the table. If you add a `WHERE` clause which covers all date ranges then query will work fine as well as little faster. Editing my answer to reflect it.

Comment: Good work. I had actually added a WHERE when I tested it and it was mentioned in my question so I thought you meant something else. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using case when condition:

```
 select 
      sum(case when ORDERDATE BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2017-02-16' then QUANTITY end ) as  YTD,
      sum(case when ORDERDATE BETWEEN '2017-02-01' AND '2017-02-16' then QUANTITY end ) as  MONTHY,
      sum(case when ORDERDATE = '2017-02-16' then QUANTITY end ) as  TODAYS,
      AVG(case when ORDERDATE BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2017-02-16' then QUANTITY end ) as  BOOGER
       FROM ORDERDETAILS
```

Comment: Thanks, that also worked. It would seem there are a few methods for achieving the same thing. I had already accepted an answer though, sorry. :)

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to use a different alias on the different calls to the table and put it all in one SELECT statement as follows:

```
SELECT SUM(od1.QUANTITY) AS YTD,
       SUM(od2.QUANTITY) AS MONTHLY,
       SUM(od3.QUANTITY) AS TODAYS,
       AVG(od4.QUANTITY) AS BOOGER
FROM ORDERDETAILS od1,
     ORDERDETAILS od2,
     ORDERDETAILS od3,
     ORDERDETAILS od4
WHERE od1.ORDERDATE BETWEEN CAST('2016-07-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2017-02-16' AS DATE)
  AND od2.ORDERDATE BETWEEN CAST('2017-02-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2017-02-16' AS DATE)
  AND od3.ORDERDATE = CAST('2017-02-16' AS DATE)
  AND od4.ORDERDATE BETWEEN CAST('2016-07-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2017-02-16' AS DATE)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've just tested it, on the server directly, and it's still running after 3 minutes. I can see where you're going with it but it's still running the query. There are only about 3000 records. :)

Comment: That's because you can't use BETWEEN like that. You need to add CAST('2016-07-01' AS DATE)

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer but I've accepted another answer already. Wish you'd mentioned the CAST earlier because if it had worked I would have accepted it. :)